# Does Yosemite still allow "per-user" Screen Sharing?

Tags: macos, osx-server

According to answers to questions on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/125636/can-a-mac-be-used-by-multiple-users-at-same-time) and [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/8966/mac-os-x-multi-user-thin-client-server-terminal-server/81587#81587), OS X Lion had the ability to allow multiple users to simultaneously log in from other Macs and get a VNC session with their own desktop on the target machine (not necessarily running OS X *Server*, from what I can tell).

For instance, I could connect to our (as yet un-purchased) Mac Mini from a Cafe with my Air, while my wife connects from the living room with her white MacBook, while one of our kids is actually sitting right in front of the Mini using it without screen sharing.

There is [no mention of this on Apple's web site, that I can find](http://www.apple.com/osx/all-features/#screen-sharing), but of course they're focused on ***new*** features, so that's no surprise.  It seems unlikely that they would *remove* features, but that's not without precedent.

So: can anyone confirm whether or not this feature still exists in OS X Yosemite?  (Or Yosemite Server?--although the answers to the other questions did not mention the feature requiring OS X ***Server***.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this feature still exists, and operates in the same way.

As an example, here is a connection from one Yosemite machine to another:

[image]

Comment: And I assume it eats up lots of memory, like Fast User Switching?

Comment: Yes. There's no getting around the fact that you have multiple users active at once. Shared libraries and application binaries will actually be shared in memory between the users, but all the working memory (Safari pages loaded, documents, etc) will be separate, so you will probably need about twice as much memory as a single user.