# Does macOS Sierra support multiple users simultaneously connecting to the same machine using screensharing?

Tags: macos, screen-sharing

Apparently [this was possible with Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/157938/3553), but I've never actually seen it in action, and I don't know if it has gone the way of Target Display and other cool features they've thrown away.

Comment: Did I miss something? Last I checked, Target Display Mode still worked on Sierra. :-/

Comment: Yes, but they removed it from new hardware.  The last (few?) release(s) of the iMac no longer offer that feature, even though it's a great idea, and something I've ***always*** wanted.

Comment: The Retina iMacs indeed don't have it (regardless of OS). I miss it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature still exists, yes. With some experimentation, I managed to understand the trick in knowing ***how*** to invoke that system.

My goals were to get a "not mirrored" remote desktop session going, in case I ever needed to work remotely for any reason.

TL;DR - First "screen sharing" session is always mirrored; subsequent sessions will prompt

Here are the steps to reproduce (though, not quite 100%, I noticed; unsure why):

1. The "Server" needs at least 2 users who are able to use Screen Sharing.
2. Have your "Client" launch screen sharing with the "Dummy" user.

   - Finder -> "Go" menu -> Connect to server (Command+K)
   - Enter the credentials for `dummy`
   - This is the "first screen sharing" session, and will mirror the displays.
3. Have your "Client" establish a second connection the server using your "Main" user.

   - Screen Sharing (application's name) Menu -> Connection -> New...
   - Enter the credentials for `main_user`
   - Dialog box should prompt "Dummy is already logged in. Ask for permission to share the screen, or login as [main_user]?"
   - Choose the "login as [main_user]" option.
   - This creates a "secondary screen sharing" session which will NOT be mirrored; it will be a virtual session.
4. Close the "Dummy" Screen Sharing window.
5. Close the "Main" Screen Sharing window.
6. Have your "Client" launch screen sharing with the "Main" user.

   - Somehow, `dummy` will still have a session running and the system will once again prompt the "ask permission? or just log in as yourself?" questions.

Comment: Is is possible to open 2 screen sharing connections from a same "Client" to the same "Server"?  When I tried `Menu -> Connection -> New...` it just jumps to the currently opened screen.

Comment: Yeah. It should be possible! That's the whole point of doing "New..." (step 3).

Comment: @starloke not for me. Have you tried it? OSX Sierra on both client and server.

Comment: It is possible as @starlocke described. If someone is already logged in, it should pop up the dialog. I tested it and it did not always work. Sometimes it would immediately mirror the currently running session instead of popping up the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

macOS Sierra still supports multiple simultaneous connected users. In the example below Sierra is running in a VM and *admin* is logged in. *user* is a remote screen sharing session from the VM host machine (10.9.5) – an iMac – and *root* is a remote session from a MacBook Pro (10.11.6):

[image]